# Consolidate data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, array-formulas

I have a large test assessment results array in a Google Sheets  which looks like this:

```
Question #    |   1  |  2   |  3   | 4    |  5   | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9    | etc...to Q25
Q Category    | Cat 1| Cat 3|  Cat5| Cat 1|  Cat3| Cat 1| Cat 5| Cat 5| Cat 4| 
| Student 1   |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   1  |
| Student 3   |   1  |   0  |   1  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   1  |
| Student 4   |   0  |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |   0  |
| Student 5   |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   1  |
| Student 6   |   0  |   0  |   1  |   1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |
...

| Student 207 |   1  |   0  |   0  |   1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |   1  |   1  |
```

I would like to consolidate the rows, such that I get the following results (summed points by question category for each student):

*No Question # necessary for output

```
Q Category    | Cat 1| Cat 3| Cat 4|  Cat5| 
| Student 1   |   3  |   1  |   1  |   1  |  
| Student 3   |   3  |   0  |   1  |   2  |  
| Student 4   |   0  |   2  |   0  |   1  | 
| Student 5   |   3  |   0  |   1  |   1  |  
| Student 6   |   2  |   1  |   1  |   1  |  
...
| Student 207 |   3  |   1  |  1   |   1  |
```

Not being able to see a way to create the appropriate pivot table using the initial array, I've attempted to transpose the initial array to get student names as column headers:

```
Q |Category|Student 1|Student 3|Student 4|Student 5|Student 6|...  |Student 207|
1 | cat 1  |   1     |   1     |   0     |   1     |   0     |     |   1       |  
2 | cat 3  |   0     |   0     |   1     |   0     |   0     |     |   0       |   
3 | cat 5  |   0     |   1     |   0     |   0     |   1     |     |   0       |   
4 | cat 1  |   1     |   1     |   0     |   1     |   1     |     |   1       |   
5 | cat 3  |   1     |   0     |   1     |   0     |   1     |     |   1       |  
6 | cat 1  |   1     |   1     |   0     |   1     |   0     |     |   1       |   
7 | cat 5  |   0     |   0     |   0     |   0     |   1     |     |   0       |   
8 | cat 5  |   1     |   1     |   1     |   1     |   1     |     |   1       | 
9 | cat 4  |   1     |   1     |   0     |   1     |   1     |     |   1       |   
...
25|...
```

and used a pivot table, but to get the appropriate results, I had to add student name column headers (207 of them) individually (summarized by sum) to the values category of the pivot table, which is far too time consuming. Not sure if there is a way to direct the pivot table to add all the individual students to the Values category automagically.

I am looking for a simple solution ideally.  If some combination of pivot tables and functions is possible, great. If scripting is necessary, I need ideas.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start in regards to scripting.  I was hoping there is a script out there that does something similar that I could modify if necessary.  Maybe someone has already attempted to replicate Excel's consolidate function (from Data menu). It does what I want, but I would rather not have the user of the google spreadsheet (which in the future won't be myself) leave the spreadsheet with the data and then bring it back from Excel.

Comment: Hmmm, then maybe the purpose of this website was not understood. You might want to continue your research for this script elsewhere. SO is really to ask question about what you have done if you have any problems or questions. If you haven't tried anything, it is not the place ;) Please have a look to Help section : http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter Good luck! :)

Comment: Someone asked a similar, simpler question in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921920/merge-multiple-rows-based-on-column-and-sum-values-excel-google-refine-google, and he got some suggestions. I figured it would be appropriate to do the same.

Comment: As you can see, the question is closed and you can read why just under the reason. :)

Comment: Tried to use Query (group by) on transposed array and was able to get the categories (col 1) and the first summed column (col 3) grouped by column 1): =query(TRANSPOSE('Data Points'!B:Z), "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 ",1).  But how would I extend that across all 200+ students (cols 3 through 207)?

Comment: You can always edit your own post, so you should paste your code in, instead of using comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question categories are in 'Data Points'!B2:Z2, the scores are in 'Data Points'!B3:Z209, and in the consolidation sheet the categories are listed in B1:E1 (this can be achieved by entering `=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE('Data Points'!B2:Z2))))` in B1), then in B2 of the consolidation sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT('Data Points'!B3:Z209;TRANSPOSE('Data Points'!B2:Z2)=B1:E1))`